# Is there a way to emulate Jackson's Mixins in JSON.Net?

Tags: c#, java, .net, jackson, json.net

I'm currently working on a few utility libraries to aid in the integration between two existing systems. As part of the integration process, I need to be able to convert objects to JSON.

For various reasons, I need to be able to modify the serialized field names (i.e convert camel case to snake case, and in some instances change the field name altogether).

One half of the system is written (mostly) in Java, and is entirely under my control. My preferred solution for serializing / deserializing JSON is to use Jackson. For a variety of reasons, it is considered a risk for us to modify the existing entity classes in order to apply the required attributes for Jackson to produce the correct JSON. Fortunately, Jackson provides Mixins, which essentially allow me to apply annotations dynamically. This is far, far superior to writing custom serializers and deserializers to do the same job.

The other half of the system is an ASP.Net application, and again I would like to modify as little of the existing code as I can get away with. I am currently using JSON.Net for serialization / deserialization, and it seems to support everything I need, including defining attributes to override property names.

However, one thing I can't seem to work out is whether JSON.Net supports the same concept of Mixins as Jackson does. If I can get away with it, I'd like to avoid modifying the existing .NET entity classes to include new attributes, but I can't find any documentation suggesting that this feature exists within JSON.Net.

So, does anybody know if there is a (documented / undocumented) way to apply Jackson-like mixins using JSON.Net, or will I need to write customer serializers / deserializers?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps, but there is sort of external implementation of Jackson's mix-in handling, as part of [ClassMate](https://github.com/cowtowncoder/java-classmate) project. Library does many other things too, so I don't know how easy it'd be to extract part that handles merging of regular annotations and mix-ins.

Comment: Thanks for that! I've kind of started implementing my own solution to this and it's peaked my interest a little so I'll probably just carry on with it, but I'll take a look anyway :)

Comment: Understandable -- nothing wrong in starting to write code, going for it! Good luck, I'd be interested in knowing what comes of it. I think mix-ins are a good idea, happy to see it being adopted more widely.

Comment: I've got a rough implementation working without modifying any of the original source and just overriding the existing stuff. Only problem is in the way JSON.Net ends up parsing the custom attributes makes it a little more cumbersome to apply the mixins thant I'd hoped, and the way JSON.Net is currently implemented means I need to apply the mixin attributes myself rather than just use existing code. However, my current solution works for my immediate needs, so this isn't too much of a hassle. Once I've tidied it up I'll post the solution. It's not the best but I've got a tight deadline!

Comment: Nonetheless awesome. I hope this becomes a useful thing for others to use as well, eventually.